# Categories and subcategories listing and cycle in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-paginator

I have the following categories table:

```
ID   |      Category Name       |     Date Added         |  Parent
______________________________________________________________________
  1  |    'Countries'          | '2013-10-09 04:18:09'   |    0
  2  |    'Spain'              | '2013-10-10 03:09:23'   |    1
  3  |    'Animals'            | '2013-10-17 06:39:21'   |    0
  4  |    'Dogs'               | '2013-10-16 07:31:52'   |    3
  5  |    'Saint-Bernard'      | '2013-10-15 05:33:33'   |    4
  6  |    'Cats'               | '2013-10-15 16:19:24'   |    3
  7  |    'Pitbull'            | '2013-10-01 08:12:13    |    4
```

On each page in my list view (index.phtml) i want to list 20 main categories (parent 0) and all of their children in the custom hierarchy. So the result should be something like this:

```
 Countries
      -> Spain
 Animals
      -> Dogs
            -> Saint-Bernard
            -> Pitbull
      -> Cats
```

In my CategoriesController on the indexAction i have build the following listing:

```
$categories = new admin_Model_DbTable_Categories();
$page = $this->_request->getParam('page');
if(empty($page)) { $page = 1; } 

$query = $categories
            ->select()
            ->where("parent = 0");

$this->view->categories = $categories->paginate(
               $query, 
               20, 
               $page
               );
```

My problem is that i don't know where exactly and how to build a function that cycles through each of the parents categories and gets their children also in a hierarchy.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: mysql. if you mean this.

Comment: Note, that you should use `getParam` as follows `$page = $this->_request->getParam('page', 1);`

Comment: @TudorRavoiu if page is not set, first line got $page = NULL; then second line empty(NULL) = false, so your second line will never be triggered. Second param at getParam = default value if variable is not presented at request.

Comment: so you mean something like this:
$this->view->sortoptions->by  = isset($requestparams['by'])   ? $requestparams['by']  : 'date_added' ;
could be written like this:
$this->view->sortoptions->by  = $this->_request->getParams('by', 'date_added);